# error con vue property decorator al instalar ag grid vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables, aggrid

He instalado recientemente ag grid vue como lo indica la guia: https://www.ag-grid.com/vuejs-grid/
pero al importar lo necesario para ejecutar la librería me arroja el error siguiente de la imagen,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo importado asi ag grid vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ag-grid-vue style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine" :columnDefs="columnDefs" :rowData="rowData">
    </ag-grid-vue>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import {AgGridVue} from "ag-grid-vue";

export default {
    name: 'ProductList',
    data() {
            return {
                columnDefs: null,
                rowData: null
            }
        },
        components: {
            AgGridVue
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.columnDefs = [
                {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
                {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
                {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
            ];

            this.rowData = [
                {make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000},
                {make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000},
                {make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000}
            ];
        }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

@import "../node_modules/ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-grid.scss";
@import "../node_modules/ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-theme-alpine/sass/ag-theme-alpine-mixin.scss";

</style>
```

ya probé desintalar y volver a instalar, cambie a una menor version en las dependencias de package.json pero sigue dando el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo probe y funciona segun las instrucciones y si tambien me tiro ese error el cual debes instalar `npm i --save vue-class-component`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]